# Intellij: Is it possible to automatically resolve dependencies between different modules' spring contexts?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, module, dependencies, applicationcontext

Suppose I have a bunch of modules in Intellij project. Every module has Spring context. Some modules are dependent on some others - that implies both classes dependencies and Spring context dependencies (some Spring contexts should have other contexts as their parents).
So, is there a way to automatically resolve such parenthood? E. g. maybe Intellij can see that referenced bean declaration doesn't exist in current Spring context, but exists in some other and from this intellij derives that the later should be set as a parent to the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it turned out, autoresolving parenthood between Spring contexts is not available in Intellij. You have to do that manually =(